# How to find a specific table by column name across all databases on a postgresql server?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I couldn't find a way to do that on pgadmin or psql terminal. How can I do that?

Comment: all daabaseshave a onformation_schema for that https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html

Comment: @nbk, that will only work for the database you are in when you run the query. It will not find that information for the other databases in the cluster(server).

Comment: You can't do that with a single query. That information can only be found by connecting to each database in turn.